# Dictionary of Pandas Dataframes to MultiIndex Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dict of Pandas Dataframes, say

```
d = {A: pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 2], [2, 2, 4]),
     B: pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]}
```

and I'd like to change it into a MultiIndex DataFrame like this:

```
A 0   0, 1, 2
  1   2, 2, 4
B 0   1, 1, 1
  1   2, 2, 2
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use [`pd.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) on the dictionary values, with the `keys` parameter set to the dictionary keys:

```
df = pd.concat(d.values(), keys=d.keys())
```

The resulting output:

```
     0  1  2
A 0  0  1  2
  1  2  2  4
B 0  1  1  1
  1  2  2  2
```

Comment: `pd.concat(d)` should produce the same result set