# Convert pandas concat of dataframes to multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

**Context**

So I'm iterating through a bunch of files where each file is a subject, and in each file there are 3 columns, each representing the x,y,z axis at a certain point (the lengths across files are not the same). I want to put all of them into a multi-index PD df.

**What I've tried**

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42256624/dictionary-of-pandas-dataframes-to-multiindex-dataframe) and when I do it, it seems to work

```
d_ = dict()
DATA_ROOT = "../sample_data/chest_mounted/"
cutoff_min = 0
for fileName in os.listdir(DATA_ROOT):
    if ".csv" in fileName and '.swp' not in fileName:
        with open(DATA_ROOT + fileName) as f:
            data = np.asarray(list(map(lambda x: x.strip().split(",")[1:-1], f.readlines())), dtype=np.int)
            subj_key = "Subject_" + str(fileName.split(".")[0])
            d_[subj_key] = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['x_acc', 'y_acc', 'z_acc'])
df = pd.concat(d_.values(), keys=d_.keys())
```

When I do df.head() it looks exactly like what I want (I think?)

```
                x_acc   y_acc   z_acc
Subject_1   0   1502    2215    2153
            1   1667    2072    2047
            2   1611    1957    1906
            3   1601    1939    1831
            4   1643    1965    1879
```

**The Problem**

However, when I try to index by Subject_x I get an error. Instead, I have to first do something like

```
df["x_acc"]["Subject_1"]
```

where I access the x_acc first then the Subject_1.

**Questions**

1) I had the impression that I was creating a multi-index but trying `df["x_acc"]["Subject_1"]` that does not seem to be the case. How do I transform it to that?

2) Is there any way to change the index so that I access by Subject first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for selecting - first by level of `MultiIndex` and then by column name or [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) implemented for simple selections:

```
df = df.loc['Subject_1', 'x_acc']
print (df)
0    1502
1    1667
2    1611
3    1601
4    1643
Name: x_acc, dtype: int64

df = df.xs('Subject_1')
print (df)
   x_acc  y_acc  z_acc
0   1502   2215   2153
1   1667   2072   2047
2   1611   1957   1906
3   1601   1939   1831
4   1643   1965   1879
```

---

And for more complicated selections use [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice

df = df.loc['Subject_1', idx['x_acc','y_acc']]
print (df)
   x_acc  y_acc
0   1502   2215
1   1667   2072
2   1611   1957
3   1601   1939
4   1643   1965
```

Also it seems your code should be simplify by [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
d_ = dict()
DATA_ROOT = "../sample_data/chest_mounted/"
cutoff_min = 0
for fileName in os.listdir(DATA_ROOT):
    if ".csv" in fileName and '.swp' not in fileName:
        subj_key = "Subject_" + str(fileName.split(".")[0])
        d_[subj_key] = pd.read_csv(fileName,  names=['x_acc', 'y_acc', 'z_acc'])

df = pd.concat(d_)
```

Comment: awesome! Thank you so much it worked. Also nice one re: read_csv it was way faster than what I was doing

Comment: I noticed that OP doesn't use all items in the rows of the file, only slicing [1:-1], so you need to modify the `pd.read_csv` a little bit.

Comment: @StayFoolish - Yes, if need remove first and last row - `d_[subj_key] = pd.read_csv(fileName,  names=['x_acc', 'y_acc', 'z_acc']).iloc[1:-1]` should working.